# Evaluating $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n}{3^n}$

Tags: summation

How can i prove that $ \sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n}{3^n}=\frac{3}{4}$?

I tried to find some pattern but didn't succeed

Comment: Differentiate $\sum x^n$

Comment: $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n}{3^n} = \sum_{n=0} \sum_{m=1}^n \frac{1}{3^n}.$ Now rearrange this sum and use facts about geometric series. A picture might help on how to rearrange the sum.

Comment: @L.F. how differentiate helps here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another approach:  As the series converges, let L denote its limit.  Now you have $$L=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n}{3^n}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty  \frac{n}{3^n}= \frac{1}{3}\sum_{n=1}^\infty  \frac{n}{3^{n-1}}=  \frac{1}{3}\sum_{n=0}^\infty  \frac{n+1}{3^{n}}= \frac{1}{3}\left[\sum_{n=0}^\infty  \frac{n}{3^{n}}+\sum_{n=0}^\infty  \frac{1}{3^{n}}\right] =\frac{1}{3}\left[L+ \sum_{n=0}^\infty  \frac{1}{3^{n}}\right].$$
Now just use the usual formula for the limit of a geometric series, and solve algebraically for $L$.

Comment: It's.. it's beautiful

Comment: Both fantastically simple and simply fantastic.+1!